# Custom product option - tree of categories/files

Tags: opencart

Good morning all,

I've been searching for a module for a while now, however before biting the bullet and building it my self (to replicate functionality I already have on a bespoke version of the site,) I just wanted to double check that no one else knew of one first.

Essentially I want my client to be able to create a product in OpenCart and then within the custom fields, they can define an unlimited number of categories and files that once this product is purchased, the customer can download any of the files defined within.

I can build most of the functionality, however building in such a custom option to the product is not something I've seen or done before, so just wanted to check.

Any idea's?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is something highly bespoke and as such I'd be amazed if there was something available already that did this. I've seen the vast majority of the extensions used on the extension store, and never come across one that does anything like this

Comment: Thanks Jay, that's pretty much what I needed to hear. Now I need to investigate the best method to do this ;) - Thanks again :)

Comment: I think *highly bespoke* is overdone, as I never heard of such a functionality request (I mean exactly the ability of creating a product with unlimited amount of downloadable files). On the other hand, highly bespoken is the functionality of *customers being able to create and sell their products* in general - with many variations of final functionality, so probably this could not be all satisfied within just one module.